# Is it overall more efficient to convert list to set when checking if a value is in the set

Tags: python, time-complexity

I was reading up on some best practices for speed in python and found [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed) which says:

> Membership testing with sets and dictionaries is much faster, **O(1)**, than searching sequences, **O(n)**.
>
> When testing "a in b", b should be a set or dictionary instead of a list or tuple.

But if say i have a list `long_list` and I want to find out if item `list_item` is in `long_list` like:

```
list_item in long_list
```

Would it under any circumstance be faster to do:

```
list_item in Set(long_list)
```

Seeing as I think list to set or dict conversion on average should be **O(n)** in itself. (?)

Or is it always better to just go with whichever data-type I'm already working with?

Comment: converting list to set takes O(n) too

Comment: Whether it is efficient or not depends on how many membership tests you expect to do. If it is just a single one as your example suggests, conversion to `set` is probably not worth it.

Comment: If you can amortize the cost of building the set over many lookups, it makes sense. Otherwise, you are just adding one O(n) cost on top of another.

Comment: You would never do `item in set(long_list)`.  That would make no sense.  It only makes sense if you convert the list to a set *once*, then make *multiple* membership tests, e.g. `s = set(long_list)` followed by a loop with lots of `item in s` tests in it.

Comment: @chepner Is it really *adding* one O(n) cost on top of another? Isn't it rather *replacing* one O(n) cost by another plus (usually) an O(1) cost? And the replacing O(n) could have a much smaller hidden constant, as in the case in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to be doing multiple lookups on `long_list`, it is worth it.  Otherwise, it is not.

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'x = list(range(10000))' '1234 in x'
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.71 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit -s 'x = list(range(10000))' '1234 in set(x)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 61.4 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit -s 'x = set(list(range(10000)))' '1234 in x'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0198 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would it under any circumstance be faster to do: `list_item in Set(long_list)`

Yes, here's one where it's about 240 times faster:

```
from timeit import timeit

# Setup the circumstance
b = ['c' * 100000 + chr(i) for i in range(100)]
set(b)
a = b[-1]

# Measure
for _ in range(3):
    print(timeit(lambda: a in b,      number=1000))
    print(timeit(lambda: a in set(b), number=1000))
    print()
```

Output:

```
1.3284053
0.005440200000000006

1.3530345000000001
0.005345699999999898

1.3339443000000002
0.0056618999999997754
```

That first `set(b)` during setup of the circumstance makes the strings compute and store their hashes. You could do `for s in b: hash(s)` instead, I was just lazy.

CPython version used: Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Results [on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DisloyalTimelyWordprocessing) with its current Python version 3.8.1 64-bit (and I think it's CPython on Linux):

```
1.2134423210000023
0.0042260629998054355

1.268552630999693
0.005732013999931951

1.1268463759997758
0.003574737000235473
```

---

**Update**

Here's a case where the `set` version is more than a million times faster for a single check, and you can increase the factor as much as you want by slowing down comparisons further:

```
from timeit import timeit

setup = '''
from time import sleep
class C:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        sleep(10)
        return self.value == other.value
b = [C(1), C(2)]
a = b[-1]
'''

for _ in range(3):
    for stmt in 'a in b', 'a in set(b)':
        t = timeit(stmt, setup, number=1)
        print('%10.7f' % t, 'seconds for: ', stmt)
    print()
```

Output:

```
10.0001129 seconds for:  a in b
 0.0000056 seconds for:  a in set(b)

10.0008811 seconds for:  a in b
 0.0000071 seconds for:  a in set(b)

10.0005529 seconds for:  a in b
 0.0000062 seconds for:  a in set(b)
```

Comment: There is some internal caching going on that affects you timings. If I do `t = time.time(); a in set(b); time.time() - t` twice, the second one is two orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @chepner Did your setup include `set(b)` like I did?

Comment: Why should it? If that has an effect, then it's to populate a cache whose time isn't accounted for by `timeit`.

Comment: @chepner Yes, that's precisely the purpose. OP asked for "any circumstance", and that's part of my circumstance.

Comment: If I time a *single* call to `a in b` vs `a in set(b)`, in separate Python instances, the former is 4x faster.

Comment: Then you're making an assumption about the internal implementation, and you may as well write `s = set(b); a in s`.

Comment: I wouldn't call an actual measurement an assumption.

Comment: It's a measurement *in* a particular implementation. There is no guarantee that an isolated call to `set(b)` will make a later call to `set(b)` faster in another implemantion. This answer is misleading, at best.

Comment: Ok, I added version information and also reproduced it on repl.it. I don't see how it's misleading. I believe I properly answer (with demonstration) the quoted question.

Comment: Because you are relying on `set(b)` being cached in memory, which *is not guaranteed* to actually happen. If you change `number=1000` to `number=1`, you'll see that for a *single* lookup, which cannot take advantage of any such cache, is slower if you call `set` first.

Comment: Wait, no. It's not `set(b)` that's being cached. It's the string hashes.

Comment: @chepner Was that your mistake the whole time? If it was the `set` being cached, I'd agree that would be very unexpected. But string hashes being cached is something I'd expect and which might even be guaranteed (at least implicitly with runtime guarantees). I couldn't find documentation talking about that, but at least the note at the end [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) talks about importance of string hashes and performance, and I'd be surprised if string hashes were *not* cashed. I think at least in CPython, it has been done for many years.

Comment: Added a note that we can do `for s in b: hash(s)` instead. And of course instead of strings I could write my own data type with slow comparisons and fast hashes. That way I could make the `set` version arbitrarily much faster than the non-`set` version, as much as I want, including for a single check.

Comment: @chepner Added such a case where a single `a in set(b)` is a million times faster than a single `a in b`, without caching or other uncertain things.